# Minimizing memory usage of a breadth first search

Tags: c++, memory-management, breadth-first-search

In my the following code, I am traversing a graph through `breadth first search`. The code constructs the graph while it is traversing. This is a very large graph, with a fan out of 12. Due to this, any time the depth of the `breadth first search` increases, I want to destruct the layer above it in an attempt to minimize memory usage. How could I design an algorithm to do so?

```
string Node::bfs(Node * rootNode) {
QQueue<Cube *> q;
q.enqueue(rootNode);

while (!(q.empty())) {
    Node * currNode = q.dequeue();
    currNode->constructChildren();
    foreach (Node * child, currNode->getListOfChildren()) {
        q.enqueue(child);
    }
    if (currNode->isGoalNode()) {
        return currNode->path;
    }
}
```

Comment: `the code constructs the graph while it is traversing.` We love to see that code. A BFS is supposed to traverse already existing graph.

Comment: I've edited the post to include a code sample.

Comment: one correction i would suggest is..you should check if the `currentNode` is the `GoalNode` immediately once you it dequeue. Saving one useless construction/enqueue of children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With constant fanout and assuming a tree-like graph, the number of nodes that have been visited by a BFS is almost the same as the number of nodes on the fringe. (e.g. in a tree with fanout K, each level n has K^n nodes, and the number of nodes with lower depth than n is also Theta(K^n)).

Hence, storing the fringe will already take up alot of memory. So if memory is a very big problem, an "equivalent" technique such as iterative deepening DFS may be much better.

But if you want to destroy the "visited" nodes, then some way of tracking what has been visited (in the case of a general graph; if it *is* a tree then there's no problem) needs to be devised. In which case more information on the graph is needed.

**EDIT** on why iterative deepening DFS is better.

The fringe (unvisited nodes that are to be adjacent to the visited nodes) in a BFS is O(K^n) in size, n being the current depth. The fringe for DFS is O(n) in size.

Iterative deepening DFS has the same fringe size as DFS, and gives the same result as BFS, because it "simulates" BFS.

Comment: I have read a little bit about an iterative deepening DFS. Could you explain how it has better space complexity?

Comment: besides the graph storage, it only stores the current path from the start of the search.

Comment: and since you don't need to store the graph (since it can be "generated"), you don't need that part. so the memory taken is linear in the path length (i.e. "depth")

Comment: Forgive me if I'm mistaken, but isn't the graph storage the problem? There is not really any path data (other than a member string).

Comment: if a node's neighbours can be computed from the node itself (as your problem seems able to), then you can construct the neighbours when you need them, and destroy them when you're done. It is similar to your original idea of destroying the visited nodes in a BFS. However, in a DFS context, this reduces the storage requirement to linear in the current depth.

Comment: @dfetter88 in BFS your QQueue object must keep every object who's children you haven't examined yet.  Every time you remove one item from the queue you had up to 12 more children thus the QQueue explodes in space very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Breadth-first search inherently [has exponential space complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search#Space_complexity). Any tricks will make only marginal impacts in the memory requirements for large graphs. You're better off using depth-first search if you want tractable space complexity.